# firebase firestore multiple query with orderby

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sql-order-by, where-clause

```
var book = {
     name: 'AAA',
     color: 'black',
     material: 'leather',
     pages: '50',
     style: 'love',
     query: {
          AAA: true,
          black: true,
          leather: true,
          50: true,
          love: true,
     }
}
```

This is what I set in firestore document. Code will append `.where(query.keyword, "==", true)` based on the number of keywords the user input. Like user inputs `black leather`, code will be:

```
firestore.collection('books').where(query.black, "==", true).where(query.leather, "==", true)
```

In the end will add `.orderBy('update', 'desc')` to list books. The accuracy depends on keywords numbers. But code changed and never used before, I will be asked to set index first. If i do not set index first, I will get `FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here:`. So, my question is:

If my data set in correct way, Can it create index automatically? or how to query with multi-keyword?

If my data set in wrong way, how to set a data that is convenient for multi-keyword search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can it create index automatically?

No, you cannot. According to the official documentation, Cloud Firestore by default automatically creates an index for each individual field in an existing document. Complex indexes required for multiple properties in a document, can only be created manually at this moment in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

If you need to use multiple `where()` function calls, please not that an index is required only if you order your elements, otherwise will work perfectly fine.

However, if you find yourself in a position in which you need to programmatically create indexes, in my opinion you should consider augmenting your data structure (if it's possible) to allow a reverse lookup. For example, you can duplicate some data by creating a `blackLists` collection where you keep the lists for each black book.